# jQuery: where do i find sliders for fancy interfaces?

Tags: jquery

I would like to realize a web app using a fancy interface; what i need is (i think) an object to be a a mix of Accordion/Slider/Carousel to contain html forms and objects to be dragged and dropped inside other containers in the same window.
I've seen many sliders for images but i've still not found something that can be used for representing web forms in fancy way.
Can anyone help me in finding it?

Comment: You can make any form fancy with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

The best choice for a fancy interface with jquery is [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html) gives you many options and possibilites. Worth giving a look. As an example here is a [form](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/wizard.html).

Comment: ye Jquery tools is really impressive

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't go for completely already written slider because in my knowledge their is no slider exists which exactly matches your requirements.

It's better if you find a good slider(their are already so many) which almost near to your requirements then develop it more  as per your requirements.

If you want to enhance you web forms in a fancy way then try this: http://www.queness.com/post/204/25-jquery-plugins-that-enhance-and-beautify-html-form-elements

Comment: here i am not only discussion about sliders the same also applied to Accordion/Carousel/drag & drop etc.